# Rails Rating System with strange helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, rating

there's an issue, that is bothering me.
I'm following this "Ruby on Rails"-Tutorial to implement an ajaxified rating system
http://eighty-b.tumblr.com/post/1569674815/creating-an-ajaxified-star-rating-system-in-rails-3

Die author uses a self written helper method called "rating_ballot" which seems pretty redundant to me, because it checks if a rating has been given yet and otherwise forms a new one with

```
    current_user.ratings.new
```

But that actually is being done more or less in the ratingscontroller

using this helper method the form looks like this

```
= form_for(rating_ballot, :html => { :class => 'rating_ballot' }) do |f|
```

But any other form (for example posting reviews) uses the instance variable instead of a helper method.

I want the form_for tag to look like this

```
= form_for(@rating, :html => { :class => 'rating_ballot' }) do |f|
```

but this only works for updating ratings, not creating new ones.

why is this "rating_ballot" so important ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on that part

```
def rating_ballot
    if @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_photo_id(params[:id])
        @rating
    else
        current_user.ratings.new
    end
end
```

It try to find out @rating if exists and create new instance if not exsits

you can do it in you controller for example:

```
 @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_photo_id(params[:id])
 @rating ||= current_user.ratings.new # create instance if did not find existing once
```

ans then use it in form like you wrote

Comment: how exactly would I place this in my methods? the @rating variable is already set with Rating.new... so why do I need current_user.ratings.new?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the value of `@rating` is nil, which is why using this form for the `#create` action isn't working. The first argument should be a `new` object, or an object that represents an existing record, in order to create or update, respectively.

Another alternative way of using the `form_for` method is to supply a symbol representing the name of the class and also specifying the `:url` argument according to how your routes are specified. This is only good for creating though since the symbol doesn't represent an existing record.